# Setting links between tables in sqlite3. Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

Sorry maybe for the stupid question but I'm new. When I create tables using this command `rails g model Post title:string description:text`. How can I further make a connection between another table by?

Or  will have enough in the models table select `belongs_to`? And thus the connection will be already established and you will not need to install anything in the migration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to "connect" the posts table (Post model), with whatever you already have, like a users table, to make an one-to-many association you can use the `references` *as a kind of type*, which will generate an entry on the migration file for creating a foreign key column on your (posts) table.

```
create_table :posts do |t|
  t.references :user
  ...
end
```

So the command could be:

```
$ rails generate model Post title:string description:text user:references
```

There I'm using `user` as an example, it can be any other.

The model generated will already have the `belongs_to` association specified, like:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  ...
```

What you need then is to add the `has_many` association in the User model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts
  ...
```